# Slow BIND9 startup with large response policy zone on Raspberry Pi

Tags: dns, raspberry-pi, bind

I've setup a local copy of BIND9 as a caching DNS forwarder on my local network. I've also configured it with a large `response-policy` zone as a network-wide adblock. With the introduction of the RPZ, startup time went from sub-second to minutes.

The RPZ has about 200K entries and is around 7.5 MiB on disk. During startup `named` pegs the processor at 100%, but after finishing it's startup procedure usage drops to near-zero. I suspect this is due to `named` being run on a old Raspberry Pi (model B).

Is there a more efficient storage format I could provide to `named` to reduce boot time? Can the already-parsed zone be dumped in a native format after the first parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after a bit of digging in the Bind documentation. The format of the zone file can be controlled via the [`masterfile-format`](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/zone.html#masterfile-format) option (in the zone block). The bind distribution comes with a tool called `named-comilezone` that will convert between the `text` (slow) and `map` (fast) file formats.

```
# To convert a text zone file to a map file
$ sudo named-compilezone -f text -F map \
    -o /var/named/rpz.example.com.zone.map  \
    rpz.example.com \
    /var/named/rpz.y2k38.date.zone  

/var/named/rpz.example.com.zone:3: using RFC1035 TTL semantics
zone rpz.example.com/IN: loaded serial 2
dump zone to /var/named/rpz.example.com.zone.map...done
OK


# To convert it back to text in order to view the contents
# just run the command in reverse
$ sudo named-compilezone -f map -F text \
    -o /var/named/rpz.example.com.zone  \
    rpz.example.com \
    /var/named/rpz.y2k38.date.zone.map
```

**Be sure to correct the permissions on the output file before starting bind again**

```
sudo chown named /var/named/rpz.example.com.zone{,.map} 
sudo chmod 640 /var/named/rpz.example.com.zone{,.map}
```

Also note that the map format takes more disk space than the text format.

```
-rw-r-----  1 named named  7638511 Jan 21 07:50 rpz.example.com.zone
-rw-r-----  1 named named 41967072 Jan 22 06:54 rpz.example.com.zone.map
```

## HOWEVER

As of Bind 9.11.2.P1 for whatever reason the `map` format is not supported for `response-policy` zones, in particular. It seems it has been this way since the format was added (9.10). I'm still digging through the code and bugtracker to see if this is a known situation or not. In Bind 9.11.2.P1, the zone is "successfully" loaded with no stated errors but no `response-policy` behavior occurs (as if file was empty).